# Using throwable lambda in method param?

Tags: java

I want to make my try catch and run method general to avoid repeat my same commands. But I don't want to use Command pattern for each of my functions. Instead I want to use lambda here:

So let me show what I need:

my code is Rest Api class which I call one or some services. These services can throw `ApplicationException`.

```
@POST
@Path("/path1")   
public Response saveConfigs1(ConfigDTO configDTO1) {
    try {
       myConfigService.save(configDTO);
        return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (ApplicationException exception) {
        return Response.serverError().entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
} 

@POST
@Path("/path2")   
public Response saveConfigs1(ConfigDTO configDTO1) {
    try {
       myConfigService2.save(configDTO);
        return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (ApplicationException exception) {
        return Response.serverError().entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

I want to avoid check for exception here. So my methods will be like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/path2")   
public Response saveConfigs1(ConfigDTO configDTO1) {
    return restCaller(() -> {
         // my throwable service calling
    })
    
}
```

And I just have a one caller:

```
Response restCaller(Runnable or what? callable){
    try {
       Object result = callable();
        return Response.ok(result).build();
    } catch (ApplicationException exception) {
        return Response.serverError().entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

I don't know how can I implement restCaller and what can be its parameter. Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: `Supplier<Response>`maybe?

Comment: Minor nitpick: I think that the term you're looking for is "lambda". "Lambada" is the name for a type of [Brazilian dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambada)

Comment: Also, this isn't AOP

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use [GlobalExceptionHandler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) and handle the exception case in that?